# Trying to create Javascript clock with future date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to create a Javascript clock that is 3 months and 15 days and 280 years into the future from the current date... So far I have managed to figure out how to get the month and year to display somewhat correctly... but for example the current date reads as "Friday, December 45, 2295" I'd like to figure out how I can get it so the correct date would read as January 14, 2296.

Here's my code so far:

```
    function date_time(id)
    {
    date = new Date;
    year = date.getFullYear() + 280;
    month = date.getMonth() + 3;
    months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    if(month = "00") {d = 31} if(d>31);
    if(month = "01") {d = 28} if(d>28);
    if(month = "02") {d = 31} if(d>31);
    if(month = "03") {d = 30} if(d>30);
    if(month = "04") {d = 31} if(d>31);
    if(month = "05") {d = 30} if(d>30);
    if(month = "06") {d = 31} if(d>31);
    if(month = "07") {d = 31} if(d>31);
    if(month = "08") {d = 30} if(d>30);
    if(month = "09") {d = 31} if(d>31);
    if(month = "10") {d = 30} if(d>30);
    if(month = "11") {d = 31} if(d>31);
    d = date.getDate() + 15;
    day = date.getDay();
    days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    if (d < 10) {
        d = "0" + d;
    }
    h = date.getHours();
    if(h<10)
    {
            h = "0"+h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if(m<10)
    {
            m = "0"+m;
    }
    s = date.getSeconds();
    if(s<10)
    {
            s = "0"+s;
    }
    result = ''+days[day]+', '+months[month]+' '+d+', '+year+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
    setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not that much difficult, try this out.

[check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgnsgkb4/2/)

// 3 months and 15 days and 280

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var date = new Date();
 var newDate = new Date(date.getFullYear()+280,date.getMonth()+2,date.getDate()+15);// I m adding 2 to month because it returns from 0-11 not from1-12 thats why for 3 months later i m adding 2.
    alert("Today : "+ date);
    alert("after 3 months and 15 days and 280 Years : "+newDate);
});
```

Comment: There is no need to create a second date, and the OP needs to add three months, not two so:  `date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear()+280, date.getMonth()+3, date.getDate()+15)`.

Comment: @RobG reason behind adding 2 in written in comments beside code, kindly read it fully.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from OAD is almost fine but the result has incorrect time.

I'm extending his idea a bit (is is just a sample, not a full solution):

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toString())
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 280);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 3);
// to get also correct time (60*60*24*15*1000) is just 15 days in milliseconds
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (60*60*24*15*1000))
console.log(d.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is for this date (Feb 14 2296) and not just so many years/months/days in the future. If calculating to a specific date work in to UTC time so that it does not matter where you are you still get the same date.

```
var t = new Date(); // get time.
t.setUTCDate(t.getUTCDate() + 15);  // calculate in universal time
t.setUTCMonth(t.getUTCMonth() + 3);
t.setUTCFullYear(t.getUTCFullYear() + 280);
console.log(t) // display local time
```

Comment: In this case, using UTC methods doesn't offer any benefits. The year, month and date can all be set in one call, see [*setFullYear*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.setfullyear).

Comment: If the date is not known only the amount of time to that date is known then you should use UTC time if the audience is international. For in 6 hours my local time will be ahead by one day. Using local time will give me feb 15? You need to fix a common time when ever you calc for a Date (day, month, year)

Comment: Neither is known, all that is known is a period to add to the current Date and time. It doesn't matter if the audience is international or not. 280 years, 3 months and 15 days represents a different amount of time depending on when it starts. Use UTC if it suits.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few issues:

```
function date_time(id)
{
date = new Date;
```

Code should be indented for readability, Variables should be kept local with *var*. Calling *new Date* without *()* is OK, but it's clearer to use parenthesis:

```
function date_time(id) {
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear() + 280;
  var month = date.getMonth() + 3;
```

then:

```
months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
```

It's cleaner to create an array using an array initialiser:

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
            'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
```

In the following:

```
if(month = "00") {d = 31} if(d>31);
```

the second *if* block does nothing. The number of days in a particular month is based on the month and year. There are plenty of answers here how to do that, but it can be as simple as (given a Date object named *date*):

```
var daysInMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
```

But the value of *d* is immediately overwritten (and is the source of your error):

```
d = date.getDate() + 15;
day = date.getDay();
```

and *day* is still the original day.

```
days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
```

Again, an array literal would be cleaner. The following pads single digit numbers:

```
if (d < 10) {
    d = "0" + d;
}
```

and so on. It's simpler to write a short function to pad numbers with up to 3 zeros:

```
function pad(n, c) {
  return ('000' + n).slice(-1*c);
}
```

and use it like:

```
pad(3, 3); // '003'

result = ''+days[day]+', '+months[month]+' '+d+', '+year+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s;
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1000');
```

To ensure that the timeout runs just after the next full second (and so doesn't seem to skip as it runs later on each call), set the lag using the current milliseconds:

```
var lag = 1020 - date.getMilliseconds();
```

Anyway, the final function can look like:

```
function date_time(id) {
  var date = new Date();

  // Increment date by 280 years, 3 months and 15 days
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 280, date.getMonth() + 3, date.getDate() + 15)

  // Arrays for month and day names
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
                'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');

  // Pad function
  function pad(n, c) {
    return ('000' + n).slice(-1*c);
  }

  // Set the lag to the next call
  var lag = 1020 - date.getMilliseconds();

  // Format for output
  var dateString = days[date.getDay()] + ', ' +
                   months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' +
                   date.getDate() + ', ' +
                   date.getFullYear() + ' ' +
                   pad(date.getHours(), 2) + ':' +
                   pad(date.getMinutes(), 2) + ':' +
                   pad(date.getSeconds(), 2);
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = dateString;
  setTimeout('date_time("' + id + '")', lag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it easily via jquery and html:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="TodayDate" id="TodayDate" />
<input type="text" name="futureDate" id="futureDate"  />
<input type="text" name="formattedDate" id="formattedDate"  />
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var todaydate = new Date();
    var futureDate = new        Date(todaydate.getFullYear()+280,todaydate.getMonth()+3,todaydate.getDate()+15);
    $("#TodayDate").val(todaydate);
    $("#futureDate").val(futureDate);
   });
```

more u can also set format as per your need by adding jquery ui plugin in your page.for that purpose you need this code:

```
$("#formattedDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', new Date(futureDate)));
```

and if you want to get future month, year and days seperatly that is also much easier

Comment: Gratuitous use of an untagged, unrequested library is seriously bad form. Input elements do not have closing tags.